# CCAvenue and Magento

Tags: magento, integration, ccavenue

I would like to know when CC Avenue API is integrated with Magento v1.7.02, how does the user interface looks like? Does it offer options like Credit Card, Debit Card, NetBanking or just simply redirects to CC Avenue website for payment?

PS :The API i'm refering to is the one provided by CCavenue and not the one available on magento commerce by junaid bhura.

Answer (score 0):

here i can suggest you one free magento extension.

It is already available at [magento commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cc-avenue-payment-gateway-9644.html) Also see [pain one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ccavenue-payment-gateway-9790.html) you can also read more information at this module description. And as per i know it is only supporting credit and debit card. currently it is not supporting net banking as per my knowledge with this extension.

just go throw carefully.

i am not promoting or any company's extension here also i am not associate with any of the concern person of this extension.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: thank you liyakat for that response. Let me assure you that i have gone through all the available literature on this topic. My question is does the CCavenue api provides different payment options in magento shopping cart or do i have to make different modules for that?

Comment: welcome @JimTodd, As per free extension comment and review you should go with the free extension. and if you wan to be more clear just install it and try. and also you can contact to customer support if they provide more service with magento also. Will pls acpt my answer so some one can use in future.